# How can I capture constant expression in annotation processor?

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to be able to detect how the name* variable was initialized in the following code sample and if name* was inlined or not. Is that possible?

```
@FancyAnnotation
public static final String name1 = new String("B1");

@FancyAnnotation
public static final String name2 = "B2";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ElementVisitors can be used to detect constant initializer.

```
boolean usesConstantValue = element.accept(new ConstantValueDetector(), null);

...

private static class ConstantValueDetector extends SimpleElementVisitor8<Boolean, Void> {
  @Override
  public Boolean visitVariable(VariableElement e, Void aVoid) {
    super.visitVariable(e, aVoid);
    return e.getConstantValue() != null;
  }
}
```